# multiple properties in spring. property in PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer class

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, properties

I'm trying to create spring project. My goal is build project for jar and war in the future. 
I use abc.properties file in the classpath which contains "conf.path.dir" property. War and jar projects use configuration from different locations. And I'm about to replace abc.properties at build time and use that to configure my PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer bean.

```
<bean id="first" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
      autowire-candidate="false">
    <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true"/>
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:abc.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="second" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer" depends-on="first">
    <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true"/>
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:ax/add.properties</value>
            <value>${conf.path.dir}/main.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Unfortunately parameter cannot be determined and I got the following error:

```
{2015\04\01 11:11:58} (ERROR) #com.mys.FooService# The service got unexpected error: 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException: Could not load properties; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [${conf.path.dir}/main.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyResourceConfigurer.postProcessBeanFactory(PropertyResourceConfigurer.java:87)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:694)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:669)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:461)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at com.mys.FooService.start(FooService.java:149)
    at com.mys.FooService$1ServiceInstanceLock.<init>(FooService.java:12)
    at com.mys.FooService.main(FooService.java:137)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [${conf.path.dir}/main.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:157)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.EncodedResource.getInputStream(EncodedResource.java:143)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderUtils.fillProperties(PropertiesLoaderUtils.java:98)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderSupport.loadProperties(PropertiesLoaderSupport.java:175)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderSupport.mergeProperties(PropertiesLoaderSupport.java:156)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyResourceConfigurer.postProcessBeanFactory(PropertyResourceConfigurer.java:78)
    ... 13 more
```

Spring version: 3.2.4
How to fix that and resolve "conf.path.dir" from abc.properties?

Comment: I have the same problem at the moment. I think it's not possible to use properties of the first placeholder in the second placeholder, but only environmental properties. Did you find a solution at the end?

Comment: @superbly, You are absolutely right. Variables become available after the initialization of the PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.
I just created new bean <bean id="envProperties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
        <property name="location" value="classpath:environment.properties"/>
    </bean>
after added it to propertyconfigurer bean
<value>#{envProperties['my.init.dir']}/main.properties</value>

Comment: Was also thinking about that. At the end I used the following: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31205614/606496

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing

```
<value>${conf.path.dir}/main.properties</value>
```

with

```
<value>file:///#{conf.path.dir}/main.properties</value>
```

That should solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but it didn't help
"org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E:(pos 0): Field or property 'conf' cannot be found on object..."

Comment: abc.properties file: \n app.root.dir = . \n conf.path.dir = ${app.root.dir}/conf

Comment: try defining it in your web.xml file as a context-param