# Use properties of other property placeholder in own property placeholder configurer

Tags: java, spring

I try to implement an own `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` which uses properties of an other `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` in the constructor. I tried doing it like this.

```
<!-- load properties which are used in second configurer -->
<context:property-placeholder 
        location="classpath:config.properties" ignore-unresolvable="true" order="1" /> 

<bean class="com.example.MyPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <!-- use property of other file -->
        <constructor-arg value="${password}" />
        <property name="location">
            <value>file:config.properties</value>
        </property>
        <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true" />
</bean>
```

config.properties

```
password=1234
```

But the property `${password}` in the constructor of `MyPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` is not resolved.

What is my mistake?

Comment: I'm not sure why some turkey marked you down :(.  Q: You mention "conf.properties"; and your code has "config.properties" and "config2.properties".  Are there really three different files?  Or is something mis-spelled?

Comment: My mistake. I misspelled it in the question. But the files are there. I use the properties of the first placeholder in other locations and they are resolved there.

Comment: That isn't going to work (as you already experienced). using property placeholders isn't a multi step proces, they are all `BeanFactoryPostProcessor`s and run very early in the lifecycle they will not operate on each other. The only placeholder replacement that is going to work is based on system properties.

Comment: Ok. Thank you very much for this clarification. Is this also the case for PropertyOverrideConfigurer? (I tried this approach as well without luck)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I post hereby my solution I came up with to overcome this problem.

I implemented a single PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer which loads all properties and adds special functionality to some properties. This way inside the PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer you are able to use properties which are defined in the loaded property files.

config.properties

```
password=1234
```

special.properties

```
user={SPECIAL}name
```

spring config:

```
<bean
    class="com.example.MyPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true" />
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:config.properties</value>
            <value>classpath:special.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer:

```
public class MyPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer extends PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer {

    private final static String PROPERTY_PREFIX = "{SPECIAL}";

    protected Properties properties;

    @Override
    protected void convertProperties(Properties props) {
        this.properties = props;
        super.convertProperties(props);
    }

    @Override
    public String convertPropertyValue(String originalValue) {
        if (originalValue.startsWith(PROPERTY_PREFIX)) {
            return convert(originalValue.substring(PROPERTY_PREFIX.length()));
        }
        return originalValue;
    }

    protected String convert(String value){
        // access properties from config.properties
        String pw = this.properties.getProperty("password");
        // use properties and do what you need to do
        return value + pw;
    }

}
```

Maybe it helps somebody.